# RecyclerView doesn't animate when it's inside a NestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

My `RecyclerView` doesn't animate when scrolling. I've narrowed down the problem to the `NestedScrollView` that the `RecyclerView` is in. When the `RecyclerView` is outside the `NestedScrollView` it animates fine. But when it's in the `NestedScrollView` it doesn't. How can I animate the `RecyclerView` while keeping it in the `NestedScrollView`?

Here's the relevant layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainToolbar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_anim_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/searchToolbar"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                android:background="#A106A1"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <!-- dummy to catch focus -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="0px"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/searchView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    app:iconifiedByDefault="true"
                    app:searchHintIcon="@null" />

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingHorizontal="1dp" />

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here's the animation applied in the RecyclerView adapter:

```
@Override        
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) { //binds the data to the view

        holder.container.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(holder.container.getContext(),R.anim.fade_out));
        holder.nameTextView.setText(labels[position]);
        holder.packageNameTextView.setText(packageNames[position]);
        holder.iconImageView.setImageDrawable(drawables[position]);

    }
```

**Update**: Here it is using the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` instead of `NestedScrollView`. How do I make the toolbar scroll?

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainToolbar">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_anim_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/searchToolbar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:background="#A106A1"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

        <!-- dummy to catch focus -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="true"
            app:searchHintIcon="@null" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Nobody? Please? :(

Comment: I'm not sure why would you put RecyclerView in  NestedScrollVoew in the first place. This way recycling will be disabled, because NSV to caclulate size will force RV to inflate all ViewHolders( as many as list size).

Comment: How else can I make the searchBar (it's a toolbar above the recyclerView) alongside the recyclerView?

Comment: @Rinat is there a way to do it without using the NestedScrollView?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good way to put RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView. If you want to make SearchBar above RecyclerView, you can check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup).

You can also check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog) refference.

Comment: How else can I make the search bar scroll up and down alongside the RecycleView?

Comment: You can check the second refference I shared. Or you can use Collapsing Toolbar with RecyclerView or EditText and RecyclerView inside ScrollView.

Comment: I will try Collapsing Toolbar today. Will report if it works.

Comment: I've been trying all day to use the Collapsing Toolbar layout and it won't work. If the code is the same as above shouldn't the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` be placed between `AppBarLayout` and `MaterialToolbar`? What attribites should I add or remove?

Comment: can you share how you trying?

Comment: I will post it in an answer below

Answer (score 1):

I checked your xml and modified it. It is working on my side. Please modify it according to your UI requirements.

N.B.: Check after populating data on recyclerview. First it may seem it is not working due to no data on recyclerview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_anim_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar_scrolling">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="true"
                app:searchHintIcon="@null" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In activity:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_bg_action_bar));
```

rounded_bg_action_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_purple" />

    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

rounded_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_purple" />

    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="100dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: So then I should remove the `MaterialToolbar`?

Comment: Yes. I think you can design what you want without that.

Comment: But I need the `MaterialToolBar` to create rounded edges

Comment: The SearchView is supposed to be inside of a second Toolbar other than the main Toolbar

Comment: Can you show me how do you want to have the layout? I can't visualize properly. And is rounded edges are the only reason for using material toolbar?

Comment: Hi. Isn't that for the main toolbar? The toolbar that I want collapsible is the one below it, the one with the searchview inside it.

Comment: Yes, only the searchview is collapsible

Comment: I want to collapse the second toolbar, same as it was being done in the original code when the `RecyclerView` was inside a `NestedScrollView`

Comment: How it was in that case? It is not clear in the still image, can you share gif or video?

Comment: Let's just say there is a toolbar separate from the main toolbar. How do I make it collapsible with the RecyclerView?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219476/discussion-between-eishon-and-user104163).